# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host ssl://smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client()

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm using Windows 10 with **cmd**.

When I'm starting my **index.php** file, using `php index.php` I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host ssl://smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:269 Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->{closure}(2, 'stream_socket_c...', 'C:\\Users\\barte\\...', 272, Array)
#1 C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(272): stream_socket_client('ssl://smtp.gmai...', 0, '', 30, 4, Resource id
#98)
#2 C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(58): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->establishSocketConnection()
#3 C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(143): Swift_Transport_Strea in C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 269

Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host ssl://smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:269 Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->{closure}(2, 'stream_socket_c...', 'C:\\Users\\barte\\...', 272, Array)
#1 C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(272): stream_socket_client('ssl://smtp.gmai...', 0, '', 30, 4, Resource id
#98)
#2 C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(58): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->establishSocketConnection()
#3 C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(143): Swift_Transport_Strea in C:\Users\barte\Desktop\PHP\3\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 269
```

---

My **index.php** file:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport("ssl://smtp.gmail.com", 465);
$transport->setUsername("mymail");
$transport->setPassword("******");

$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = new Swift_Message();
$message
    ->setFrom("mymail@gmail.com")
    ->setTo("mymail@gmail.com")
    ->setSubject("Hello!")
    ->setBody("Hello, this is example body");

$mailer->send($message);
```

Here's my **composer.json** file:

```
{
    "name": "bartek/3",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Bartek",
            "email": "mymail@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.2"
    }
}
```

---

When I'm typing **composer --version** I'm getting:

> PHP temp directory (C:\Users\barte\AppData\Local\Temp) does not exist
> or is not writable to Composer. Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini
> Composer version 1.10.5 2020-04-10 11:44:22

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was, I typed the password to my Google account, but I should paste the password generated in "App passwords" in google account settings there. You can generate a password like this by going to `Google Account Settings > Security > App passwords`

Note: You have to have 2-step verification enabled first. Otherwise `App passwords` won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

I prepare code recently for this purpose
**For TLS**

```
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 587,'tls'))
->setUsername('username@gmail.com')
->setPassword('password');
```

And **For SSL**

```
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 25,'ssl'))
->setUsername('username@gmail.com')
->setPassword('password');
```

Answer (score -1):

`ssl://smtp.gmail.com` is not a proper address for a mailserver. What happens if you skip the protocol and just use `smtp.gmail.com`?

Comment: I changed it and now, when I'm starting index.php I have to wait about 30 seconds, and after that it is printing, something like "... time out  ..."